# Bean creation exception in spring mobile

Tags: spring, spring-mobile

I am getting the following exception while using [sample](http://www.srccodes.com/p/article/25/spring-mobile-hello-world-example-that-includes-deviceresolver-sitepreference-urlpath-siteswitcher-and-litedevicedelegatingviewresolver)

nested exception is 
`org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.mobile.device.Device]: Specified class is an interface]` with root cause

My controller is as follows:

```
package com.srccodes.spring.controller;

import java.util.logging.Logger;
import org.springframework.mobile.device.Device;
import org.springframework.mobile.device.site.SitePreference;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

/**
 * @author Abhijit Ghosh
 * @version 1.0
 */
@Controller
public class SpringMobileHelloController {
    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(SpringMobileHelloController.class.getName());

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String sayHello(SitePreference sitePreference, Device device, Model model) {
        logger.info("SitePreference : " + sitePreference);
        logger.info("Device : " + device);

        model.addAttribute("message", "Hello World!");

        return "helloWorld";
    }
}


My dispatcher-servlet.xml is:

 (some parts omitted)

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.srccodes.spring.controller" />

    <mvc:annotation-driven>
        <mvc:argument-resolvers>
            <bean            class="org.springframework.mobile.device.site.SitePreferenceWebArgumentResolver" />            
            <bean class="org.springframework.mobile.device.DeviceWebArgumentResolver" />
        </mvc:argument-resolvers>
    </mvc:annotation-driven>

    <mvc:interceptors>
        <!-- Resolve the device which has generated the request -->
        <bean class="org.springframework.mobile.device.DeviceResolverHandlerInterceptor" />

        <!-- User's site preference -->
        <bean class="org.springframework.mobile.device.site.SitePreferenceHandlerInterceptor" />

        <!-- Redirects users to the device specific site -->
        <bean class="org.springframework.mobile.device.switcher.SiteSwitcherHandlerInterceptor" factory-method="urlPath">
            <constructor-arg value="/m" />
            <constructor-arg value="/t" />
            <constructor-arg value="/SpringMobileHelloWorld" />
        </bean>
    </mvc:interceptors>


    <!-- Device aware view resolving -->
    <bean id="liteDeviceDelegatingViewResolver" class="org.springframework.mobile.device.view.LiteDeviceDelegatingViewResolver">
        <constructor-arg>
            <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
                <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/" />
                <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
            </bean>
        </constructor-arg>

        <property name="mobilePrefix" value="m/" />
        <property name="tabletPrefix" value="t/" />
        <property name="enableFallback" value="true" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Please help me out as I am a beginner in spring mobile.This example is available in spring source official website.It is saying that device is a interface but I have used its implementing classes only.Basically I think its an error in dispatcher servlet.xml

Comment: Can [this](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?135661-Could-not-instantiate-bean-class-org-springframework-mobile-device-Device) help ?

Comment: The device filter helps for you @user2354150? Or you've found something different to use?

Answer (score 4):

Try to use Device filter:

```
    <filter>
        <filter-name>deviceResolverRequestFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.mobile.device.DeviceResolverRequestFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
```

Anyway, you can retrieve the device from `DeviceUtils`, using an `HttpServletRequest`, like this handler example..:

```
public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse arg1, Object arg2) throws Exception {
        Device device = DeviceUtils.getCurrentDevice(request);
...
}
```

I have the same problem and solve it with the second approach.

Answer (score 2):

Check if `<mvc:annotation-driven/>` is not defined anywhere else.
Simply add:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven>
    <mvc:argument-resolvers>
        <bean class="org.springframework.mobile.device.DeviceWebArgumentResolver" />

        <bean class="org.springframework.mobile.device.site.SitePreferenceWebArgumentResolver" />
    </mvc:argument-resolvers>
</mvc:annotation-driven>
```

Comment: This is covered in 2.3.2 here: http://docs.spring.io/spring-mobile/docs/current/reference/html/device.html. Of course, I ran into this by only reading 2.3.1

Answer (score 1):

In addition to leogps answer, following is the Java Config

```
    @Bean
    public DeviceHandlerMethodArgumentResolver deviceHandlerMethodArgumentResolver() {
            return new DeviceHandlerMethodArgumentResolver();
        }

     @Override
     public void addArgumentResolvers(List<HandlerMethodArgumentResolver> argumentResolvers) {
            argumentResolvers.add(deviceHandlerMethodArgumentResolver());
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add argument resolver for this.
Follow [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-mobile/docs/current/reference/html/device.html#device-web-argument-resolver)

If you'd like to pass the current Device as an argument to one of your @Controller methods, configure a DeviceWebArgumentResolver:

```
<annotation-driven>
  <argument-resolvers>
    <bean class="org.springframework.mobile.device.DeviceWebArgumentResolver" />
  </argument-resolvers>
</annotation-driven>
```

You can alternatively configure a DeviceHandlerMethodArgumentResolver using Java-based configuration:

```
@Bean
public DeviceHandlerMethodArgumentResolver deviceHandlerMethodArgumentResolver() {
    return new DeviceHandlerMethodArgumentResolver();
}

@Override
public void addArgumentResolvers(List<HandlerMethodArgumentResolver> argumentResolvers) {
    argumentResolvers.add(deviceHandlerMethodArgumentResolver());
}
```